# How to navigate to different sections of page in Gatsby (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I want to navigate to different sections in my gatsby site.
My **index.js** page is like this.

```html
<section id="#">
    Hi Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</section>
<section id="/#about">
    Hi Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</section>
<section id="/#contact">
    Hi Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</section>
```

I have tried both ways using the `<a> tag` and the `Link` component. But both are not working.

Navbar.js code

```html
<a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
  or
<Link to="#about">ABOUT</Link>
```

I have index.js inside src/pages, and Navbar.js and Layout.js inside src/components.
This is my `Layout.js` code.

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    const navMargins = {
        marginBottom: "50px",
    };

    return (
        <div className="layout">
            <div className="navbar" style={navMargins}>
                <Navbar />
            </div>
            <div className="content">{children}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/):
I'll copy the installation, usage here

1. Install

```
yarn add gatsby-plugin-anchor-links
```

2. Update gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-anchor-links`]
};
```

With offset

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links",
      options: {
        offset: -100
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

3. And the usage will be like:

```
import { AnchorLink } from "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links";

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink to="/about#team" title="Our team">
    <span>Check out our team!</span>
  </AnchorLink>
);
// => <a href="/about#team" title="Our team"><span>Check out our team!</span></a>

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink to="/about#team" title="Check out our team!" />
);
// => <a href="/about#team" title="Check out our team!">Check out our team!</a>

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink
    to="/about#team"
    title="Check out our team!"
    className="stripped"
    stripHash
  />
);
// => <a href="/about" class="stripped" title="Check out our team!">Check out our team!</a>
// => Hash will be stripped, and a full page scroll will occure onRouteChange

export default () => <AnchorLink to="/about" title="About us" />;
// => <a href="/about" title="About us">About us</a>
```

If you want to avoid using this plugin you might want to
you can invoke this in either `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`

```js
window.addEventListener('locationchange', function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(window.location.hash).offsetTop)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, is there any other way to do this without using this dependency?

Comment: It's usually much easier to use plugins for these cases as it handles unknown scenarios that pops in
YOu can listen to `document.load` event and navigate based on URL

Comment: I added this line  <AnchorLink to="#about" title="About us" /> in place of <Link> 
But it just adds #about to the URL but the page is still not scrolling.
http://localhost:8000/#about

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Can you try `/#team` instead?

Comment: Did this happens to you that a code does not work at first but then after trying several methods the original code starts working magically. The code which I wrote in the questions is working as it should. The <a> tag is working fine. Thank You so much for your assistance.